# How to prohibit specific content in files using ArchUnit in Java

Tags: java, archunit

I would like to have a rule that is checking for some specific string. let's say we don't want to see "**Objects.nonNull**" in our code base and want to have "**nonNull**" imported static.

How can I do that in **ArchUnit**? I know it is for more architecture goals, but we have it already in the project so maybe we can use it also for lower level checks.

Or how it can be done easy in other framework?

Comment: One option I can think of: use `grep` in your CI pipeline and have it fail when it finds your search string (but will you allow `Objects.(linebreak here)nonNull` or `Objects.non\u004eull`? What about `your.package.Objects.nonNull`?

Comment: ArchUnit works on the bytecode and can therefore not be used for syntactical checks.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with ArchUnit (at least I'm not aware of it and the API does not seem to provide such possibilities). It also makes sense: imports only exist in the source code, they do not exist in the generated bytecode. Therefore ArchUnit does not have access to this information.

What you can do is to define in your build pipeline a task which calls `grep` on all relevant files. Something along the lines of:

```
grep -q 'Objects\.nonNull` *.java && echo "Qualified nonNull call found! Aborting.";
```

Or maybe you are already using CheckStyle to enforce (style) rules in your code. CheckStyle provides the [Regexp](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/config_regexp.html) check since version 4.0:

> Checks that a specified pattern exists, exists less than a set number of times, or does not exist in the file.

Example:

```
<module name="Regexp">
  <property name="format" value="Objects\.nonNull"/>
  <property name="illegalPattern" value="true"/>
</module>
```